# Finding clusters of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling with that, since I'm sure that a dozen for-loops is not the solution for this problem:

There is a sorted list of numbers like

```
numbers = [123, 124, 128, 160, 167, 213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257, 400, 401, 402, 430]
```

and I want to create a dict with lists of numbers, wherein the difference of the numbers (following each other) is not more than 15. So the output would be this:

```
clusters = {
    1 : [123, 124, 128],
    2 : [160, 167],
    3 : [213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257],
    4 : [400, 401, 402],
    5 : [430]
}
```

My current solution is a bit ugly (I have to remove duplicates at the end…), I'm sure it can be done in a pythonic way.

This is what I do now:

```
clusters = {}  
dIndex = 0 
for i in range(len(numbers)-1) :
    if numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] <= 15 :
        if not clusters.has_key(dIndex) : clusters[dIndex] = []
        clusters[dIndex].append(numbers[i])
        clusters[dIndex].append(numbers[i+1])
    else : dIndex += 1
```

Comment: [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) will probably be useful in this case.

Comment: [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would make your code a bit simpler

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at both!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not strictly necessary if your list is small, but I'd probably approach this in a "stream-processing" fashion: define a generator that takes your input iterable, and yields the elements grouped into runs of numbers differing by <= 15. Then you can use that to generate your dictionary easily.

```
def grouper(iterable):
    prev = None
    group = []
    for item in iterable:
        if prev is None or item - prev <= 15:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
        prev = item
    if group:
        yield group

numbers = [123, 124, 128, 160, 167, 213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257, 400, 401, 402, 430]
dict(enumerate(grouper(numbers), 1))
```

prints:

```
{1: [123, 124, 128],
 2: [160, 167],
 3: [213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257],
 4: [400, 401, 402],
 5: [430]}
```

As a bonus, this lets you even group your runs for potentially-infinite lists (as long as they're sorted, of course). You could also stick the index generation part into the generator itself (instead of using `enumerate`) as a minor enhancement.

Comment: WOW, really cool function! I was lookig just for that. Thanks @tzaman

Comment: @wjandrea nice catch, fixed!

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([123, 124, 128, 160, 167, 213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257, 400, 401, 402, 430])
nd = [0] + list(np.where(np.diff(numbers) > 15)[0] + 1) + [len(numbers)]

a, b = itertools.tee(nd)
next(b, None)
res = {}
for j, (f, b) in enumerate(itertools.izip(a, b)):
    res[j] = numbers[f:b]
```

If you can use itertools and numpy.  Adapted [`pairwise`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for the iterator tricks. The `+1` is needed to shift the index, adding the `0` and `len(numbers)` onto the list makes sure the first and last entries are included correctly.

You can obviously do this with out `itertools`, but I like `tee`.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with no (explicit) loops using numpy / pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np

n = 15
numbers = [123, 124, 128, 160, 167, 213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257, 400, 401, 402, 430]
nnumbers = np.array(numbers)
clusters = pd.DataFrame({
    'numbers': numbers,
    'segment': np.cumsum([0] + list(1*(nnumbers[1:] - nnumbers[0:-1] > n))) + 1
}).groupby('segment').agg({'numbers': set}).to_dict()['numbers']
```

The trick is to shift the list of numbers and compare the difference with your threshold (15) to find 'breaks' between segments. Of course, first element will not be a break. Then use cumsum function to get the segments and do the group by using a set function (in case there are duplicates).
Hope this is helpful even though many years have passed since posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the generator to separate the logic: (one function does one thing)

```
numbers = [123, 124, 128, 160, 167, 213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257, 400, 401, 402, 430]

def cut_indices(numbers):
    # this function iterate over the indices that need to be 'cut'
    for i in xrange(len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] > 15:
            yield i+1

def splitter(numbers):
    # this function split the original list into sublists.
    px = 0
    for x in cut_indices(numbers):
        yield numbers[px:x]
        px = x
    yield numbers[px:]

def cluster(numbers):
    # using the above result, to form a dict object.
    cluster_ids = xrange(1,len(numbers))
    return dict(zip(cluster_ids, splitter(numbers)))

print cluster(numbers)
```

The above codes give me

```
{1: [123, 124, 128], 2: [160, 167], 3: [213, 215, 230, 245, 255, 257], 4: [400, 401, 402], 5: [430]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively simple solution that works for lists or generators. It lazily yields pairs `(group_number, element)` so you'd have to do the actual grouping separately if you needed it. (Or maybe you just need the group number.)

```py
 from itertools import tee

 def group(xs, gap=15):
    # use `tee` to get two efficient iterators
    xs1, xs2 = tee(xs)

    # the first element is in group 0, also advance the second iterator
    group = 0
    yield (group, next(xs2))

    # after advancing xs2, this zip is pairs of consecutive elements
    for x, y in zip(xs1, xs2):
        # whenever the gap is too large, increment the group number
        if y - x > gap:
            group += 1
        # and yield the second number in the pair
        yield group, y
```