# Finding clusters in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a sorted python list which looks like:

```
myList = [1,2,3,7,8,9,12,13,14,15]
```

The consecutive elements with difference 1 form the cluster. I need to dig these clusters out.

In the above example the clusters would be `1,2,3`; `7,8,9`; `12,13,14,15`

Is there a way other than to write a for loop and see where the difference between consecutive elements is > 1

Edit: The list I have is large so I want to avoid using a for loop as much as I can unless that is the only way out

Comment: cannot find the duplicate question of that one... there _must_ be one.

Comment: The for loop as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like the for-loop?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Looks like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800895/finding-clusters-of-numbers-in-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14783947/190597

Comment: Zanam, coders link has a very pythonic solution to your problem, and is asolutely what you're looking for