# How to group similar numbers with condition/range

Tags: python

the idea is to group same/similar float numbers, excluding drastic differences.

For example *group* 1.123 and 1.123, 1.322 also consider 2.01 as being in one group (additional condition is required to take into account +1 or -1).

code:

```
from itertools import groupby

x =[39.5999755859375,48.84002685546875,58.08001708984375,67.32000732421875,76.55999755859375,85.79998779296875,147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562]

groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(x, key=int)]
```

output:

```
groups
Out[129]: 
[[39.5999755859375],
[48.84002685546875],
[58.08001708984375],
[67.32000732421875],
[76.55999755859375],
[85.79998779296875],
[147.83999633789062,
 147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812],
[148.07998657226562],
[147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812,
 147.95999145507812],
[199.07998657226562,
 199.07998657226562,
 199.07998657226562,
 199.07998657226562,
 199.07998657226562]]
```

As you can see in the output  [148.07998657226562] is considered as being different instead of being among 147's

Is there any condition or function I could use inside of groupby() as a parameter to explicitly give a condition/ to take into account all those similar numbers such as 147 and 148 (+- 1).

Comment: What would be the expected result if the `x = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]`? Would that be one group since the difference between two numbers is less than 1, or would that be two groups all with a difference of 1 between their smallest and biggest elements?

Comment: [[0, 0.5], [1, 1.5], [2, 2.5]] would be the output

Answer (score 2):

Using `cluser`:

```
import cluster
data =[39.5999755859375,48.84002685546875,58.08001708984375,67.32000732421875,76.55999755859375,85.79998779296875,147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562]
cl = cluster.HierarchicalClustering(data, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
cl.getlevel(1)
```

---

```
[[39.5999755859375],
 [48.84002685546875],
 [58.08001708984375],
 [85.79998779296875],
 [67.32000732421875],
 [76.55999755859375],
 [199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562],
 [148.07998657226562,
  147.83999633789062,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812]]
```

### **Edit:**

Source/Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801233/6660373

```
data = sorted(data)

def grouper(iterable):
    prev = None
    group = []
    for item in iterable:
        if not prev or item - prev <= 1:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
        prev = item
    if group:
        yield group

list(grouper(data))
```

---

```
[[39.5999755859375],
 [48.84002685546875],
 [58.08001708984375],
 [67.32000732421875],
 [76.55999755859375],
 [85.79998779296875],
 [147.83999633789062,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  148.07998657226562],
 [199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the magic, at least for this specific case of mine.

Comment: If my answer helps then close the question by accepting it as a solution. Merry christmas in advance btw :)

Comment: the only problem remaining is to control the order. The same order has to be preserved otherwise it influences my output.  147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562 is the original order. In the output 148 comes first which shouldn't be the case, is this too complicated to handle?!

Comment: Then sort the list(data) and then pass.

Comment: the data (or the x variable in this case) is already sorted in the right manner. I'm exporting images and this is it's coordinates. Any different order changes the sequence of exportation.

Comment: @check the updated answer. Don;t change the original list then just pass the sorted list to it because this algo assumes the data to be sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can always *roll your own* algorithem. For every element check if the last group has no elements that are too different to it and if so, add it to the same group, otherwise, add a new group with the element in it.

```py
x = [39.5999755859375,48.84002685546875,58.08001708984375,67.32000732421875,76.55999755859375,85.79998779296875,147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562]

groups = []
for item in x:
    if len(groups) == 0:
        groups.append([item])
        continue
    curr_group = groups[-1]
    if all(abs(item - x) < 1 for x in curr_group):
        curr_group.append(item)
    else:
        groups.append([item])
```

**Output:**

```py
[[39.5999755859375],
 [48.84002685546875],
 [58.08001708984375],
 [67.32000732421875],
 [76.55999755859375],
 [85.79998779296875],
 [147.83999633789062,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  148.07998657226562,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812],
 [199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562,
  199.07998657226562]]
```

---

We can generalize this answer by turning this into a function:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')
def continuous_groupby(iter: Iterable[T], predicate: Callable[[list[T], T], bool]) -> list[list[T]]:
    """Divide the iterable into groups, uses the predicate to decide whether the next value should be considered in the same group or in a new one."""
    groups = []
    for item in iter:
        if len(groups) == 0:
            groups.append([item])
            continue
        curr_group = groups[-1]
        if predicate(curr_group, item):
            curr_group.append(item)
        else:
            groups.append([item])
    return groups

x = [39.5999755859375,48.84002685546875,58.08001708984375,67.32000732421875,76.55999755859375,85.79998779296875,147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562,199.07998657226562]
groups = continuous_groupby(x, lambda group, item: all(abs(item - x) < 1 for x in group))
```

**Note** for earlier versions of python, `list[T]` won't work. Instead, import `List` from `typing` and and use `List[T]`.

Comment: the only problem remaining is to control the order. The same order has to be preserved otherwise it influences my output.  147.83999633789062,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,147.95999145507812,148.07998657226562 is the original order. In the output 148 comes first which shouldn't be the case, is this too complicated to handle?!

Comment: @Ecko this method preserves the order of the elements. For this particular input, `groups[6]` is effectively a copy of `x[6:16]`.