# given a list of sorted numbers, divide into sublist based on how apart the numbers are

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Example:

```
sample_list = [1,2,4,7,9,10,15,20]
# we have some criteria where consecutive numbers >= 3 apart forms a sublist:
result_list = [[1,2,4],[7,9,10],[15],[20]]
```

in python, whats an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800895/finding-clusters-of-numbers-in-a-list/15801233#15801233

Comment: What have you tried? This should be dead-simple, no?

Answer (score 0):

Define:

```
def batches(xs, criteria):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        if len(ys) != 0 and criteria(ys[-1], x):
            yield ys
            ys = []
        ys.append(x)
    if len(ys) != 0:
        yield ys
```

Usage:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15, 20]
>>> list(batches(xs, lambda a, b: a + 3 <= b))
[[1, 2, 4], [7, 9, 10], [15], [20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` is your friend for this type of thing.  It can produce pairs of list items combined with their predecessor.  From that you can determine the indexes of "break" elements that are at or beyond the specified distance from their predecessor.

From these indexes you can use zip again to obtain start/end range values that you can use to subscript the list.

```
L = [1,2,4,7,9,10,15,20]
distance = 3

breaks = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(L,L[1:]),1) if b-a>=distance]
result = [L[s:e] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[None])]

print(result)
[[1, 2, 4], [7, 9, 10], [15], [20]]
```